# MYSQL distinct random join query

Tags: mysql, join, random, distinct

I have two tables

```
albums      fotos
------      -----
id          id
titulo      url
            fk_album
```

I would like to know how I can select from all albums that are not empty, random photos... and must be distinct... For example:

```
albums          fotos
------          ------
1 A             1 my_url_1 2
2 B             2 my_url_2 2 
3 C             3 my_url_3 1
4 D             4 my_url_4 2
5 E             5 my_url_5 3
                6 my_url_6 3
```

I want results like these: (distinct, random & join)

```
result0 -> 
       albums.id     -> 2
       albums.titulo -> B
       fotos.url     -> my_url_2 (this must be random) (or my_url_1 or my_url_4)
result1 -> 
       albums.id     -> 3
       albums.titulo -> C
       fotos.url     -> my_url_6 (this must be random) (or my_url_5 )
result2 -> 
       albums.id     -> 1
       albums.titulo -> A
       fotos.url     -> my_url_3 (the album only has this foto url)
```

I have tried many things but actually I can only get the distinct albums with photos but without random values it.

EDIT:
I was using the following query, that returns me the 5 albums with photo (all distinct...not repeating). But I get always the same photo per album. I need different photo each time (if the album has more than one photo of course)

```
select distinct
     a.id,
     a.titulo,
     f.url
 from albums as a
      inner join
          fotos as f
          on  a.id = f.fk_album
 where f.fk_album = a.id
 GROUP by f.fk_album, a.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little guessing here and am not sure what is the performance on this, but you could use something like:

```
SELECT a.id,
     a.titulo,
     f.url
 FROM albums AS a
      JOIN (SELECT url, fk_album FROM fotos ORDER BY RAND()) as f
          ON a.id = f.fk_album
 GROUP BY a.id
```

(I removed distinct, where and group by from your query, because those statements seem redundant)

Comment: error syntax: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT fk_album FROM fotos ORDER BY RAND()) as f ON a.id = f.fk_

Comment: Thank you Fox! This is working for me. Sorry, I can't upvote because I still have not enough reputation points